# How to select rows as JSON object in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, data-conversion

I'd like to convert rows to JSON object in MySQL. For example with

```
| name  | count |
| apple |   1   |
| banana|   2   |
```

the expected JSON output would be

```
{apple: 1, banana: 2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL 5.7 and 8.0 use [json_objectagg](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `name` VARCHAR(6),
>   `count` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`name`, `count`)
> VALUES
>   ('apple', '1'),
>   ('banana', '2');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT json_objectagg(`name`,`count`) jt FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> | jt                        |
> | :------------------------ |
> | {"apple": 1, "banana": 2} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=580879626cc96e744f68b63c8b8fb045)*